# Syntax highlighting for lex in gedit

Tags: syntax-highlighting, lex, gedit, gtksourceview

I know i just need a file like `/usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/javascript.lang`. Where can i find a language definition like this for lex ?

Comment: This is [GNOME Bug #641573](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=641573).

Comment: Actually, today with gedit 3.4.1, seems like its more into '/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs'

Answer (score 1):

You can find extra language definitions [here](https://live.gnome.org/GtkSourceView/LanguageDefinitions), but it doesn't look like lex is among them. I think there may not be one yet. [Here](http://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/lang-tutorial.html) is a guide to writing your own.

Comment: I am a newbie to lex so its really hard for me to write it my own :(

Comment: The point of syntax highlighting is to learn the language faster. I may be able to write one for c or javascript but lex is not something i know already